# Create excel range with list

Tags: python, list

I have tons of list of lists like this:

```
[['A1', 'D1', 'G1', 'J1', 'V1', 'A3', 'D3', 'G3'], ['A1', 'D1', 'G1', 'J1', 'M1']]
```

These are simple excel coordinates and I want to create a range based on the numbers. So if the numbers are the same the range's first element will be the 0. `element(A1)` and the second element should be the `-1`. `element(V1)`.

For example in the first list the range should be `["A1:V1","A3:G3"]`

Unfortunately, I really don't know how to do this :(

This is the code how i search for the values of the lists:

```
# Import
from openpyxl import load_workbook

# This list is the final list
big_lst = []

# Input the workbook
wb = load_workbook("new_test.xlsx",data_only=True)

# Loop over the sheets
for sheets in wb.sheetnames:
     ws = wb[sheets]
     # 1 small list = 1 sheet
     small_lst = []
     for sheet in ws:
        for val in sheet:
            for i in range(10):
                if val.value == "DATA{}".format(i):
                     small_lst.append(val.coordinate)
    big_lst.append(small_lst)
```

Comment: In python, in my program i find the elements that i need, these are strings. These strings are next to each other and after the search i get those lists(1 list equals 1 sheet). And now I'm in stuck because I don't know how to create a range.

Comment: Does each sublist always have the column identifiers in alphabetical order? Are there only ever two rows specified in each sublist?

Comment: Updated my post with my code. They are in alphabetical order and the output of the lists are based on the worksheet, almost every sheets are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assumed that all sets have cells in random order.

Made this function it will give output for a list of cells.

```
list_of_lists = [['A1', 'D1', 'G1', 'J1', 'V1', 'A3', 'D3', 'G3'], ['A1', 'D1', 'G1', 'J1', 'M1']]

alphabet_order = {'A' : 1, 'B' : 2, 'C' : 3, 'D' : 4, 'E' : 5, 'F' : 6, 'G' : 7, 'H' : 8, 'I' : 9, 'J' : 10, 'K' : 11, 'L' : 12, 'M' : 13, 
                                'N' : 14, 'O' : 15, 'P' : 16, 'Q' : 17, 'R' : 18, 'S' : 19, 'T' : 20, 'U' : 21, 'V' : 22, 'W' : 23, 'X' : 24, 'Y' : 25, 'Z' : 26 }

def columnumber(column):
    columnumber = 0
    for i in range(len(column)):
        columnumber += alphabet_order[column[i]] * (26 **(len(column) - 1 - i))
    return columnumber
    
def row(cell):
    for i, c in enumerate(cell):
        if c.isdigit():
            return cell[i:]
            
def column(cell):
    for i, c in enumerate(cell):
        if c.isdigit():
            return cell[:i]

def GiveRange(List_of_Cells):
    Range = []
    rowSet = []
    
    for i in List_of_Cells:
        r = row(i)
        if r not in rowSet:
            rowSet.append(r)
    
    for rows in rowSet:
        cells_of_row = []
        for cell in List_of_Cells:
            if row(cell) == rows:
                cells_of_row.append(cell)
        
        maxCell = cells_of_row[0]
        minCell = cells_of_row[0]       
        
        for cell in cells_of_row:
            if columnumber(column(cell)) >= columnumber(column(maxCell)):
                maxCell = cell
            elif columnumber(column(cell)) <= columnumber(column(minCell)):
                minCell = cell
        Range.append(f"{minCell}:{maxCell}")
        
    return Range
            
print(GiveRange(list_of_lists[0]))
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your requirement correctly, then this should suffice. It is assumed that each sublist contains 2 or more coordinates, that they are in alphabetical order and that no more than 2 rows are involved in any sublist

```
ML = [['A1', 'D1', 'G1', 'J1', 'V1', 'A3', 'D3', 'G3', 'A4', 'H4'],
      ['A1', 'D1', 'G1', 'J1', 'M1'], ['X1']]


def row(s):
    for i, c in enumerate(s):
        if c.isdigit():
            return int(s[i:])


def process(ml):
    r = []
    for sl in ml:
        if sl:
            _r = []
            for i, c in enumerate(sl):
                if i == 0:
                    _range = c
                    _row = row(c)
                else:
                    if (_rc := row(c)) != _row:
                        _r.append(f'{_range}:{sl[i-1]}')
                        _row = _rc
                        _range = c
            _r.append(f'{_range}:{sl[-1]}')
            r.append(_r)
    return r


print(process(ML))
```

With these data, the output will be:-

[['A1:V1', 'A3:G3', 'A4:H4'], ['A1:M1'], ['X1:X1']]

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks for the help <3.

Comment: Ohh now i see it only works with 2 sublists, didn't see ur edit sorry. Sometimes there are more than 2 sublists, baaased on the sheet.

Comment: It will work with any number of sublists. It will not work with, for example, ['A1','D1','A2','D2','A3','D3'] - i.e. it only allows for two rows per sublist. I'll work on an amendment to make it more generic